# Install DoctrineCouchDBBundle on Symfony 2.5.4 with composer

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb, composer-php

I can't install the [DoctrineCouchDBBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle), `php composer.phar update` returns :

---

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Installation request for doctrine/couchdb-odm-bundle dev-master - satisfiable by doctrine/couchdb-odm-bundle[dev-master].
- doctrine/couchdb-odm-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/couchdb-odm @dev - no matching package found.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

---

This is my *composer.json* file (the `require` part) :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/couchdb-odm-bundle": "dev-master",
    "components/bootstrap": "3.2.*"
},
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `"doctrine/couchdb-odm":  "@dev"` in the require list and run `composer update` again.

You are probably using stable mode. I stable mode if you have an indirect dependency on unstable versions need to be requried in the root. Unstable deps are only installed from the root list.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add `"doctrine/couchdb": "@dev"` too